# Why am I getting "Pipeline failed due to the user not being verified" & "Detached merge request pipeline" on a Gitlab merge request?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-pipelines

When a non-owner dev pushes a branch to our Gitlab repo, it returns a "pipeline failed" message, with the detail "Pipeline failed due to the user not being verified". On the dev's account, he's getting a prompt to add a credit card to verify him to be eligible for free pipeline minutes.

But I haven't set up any pipelines - I don't have a gitlab-ci.yml file in my repo, neither does the new branch. There are no jobs or schedules under the CI/CD tab of the project on Gitlab. So why is there a marker saying the branch failed in the pipeline?

Comment: Same Issue. This was not happening yesterday (7th June 2021).

Comment: You can use virtual debit cards , one can use paytm debit card too .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For all those still wondering, I contacted Gitlab recently & apparently it's an open issue with them. They said it's possible to merge the branches anyway, but in the end we just added the credit card details anyway (there was a temporary charge). Not ideal, but hopefully will get sorted soon.

Answer (score 13):

In my case, I was using my own runner for my project. In that case also, I got this error.

I fixed the error by disabling the shared runner in my project.
Under

```
Setting -> CICD -> Runner (Expand) -> Under the shared runner section, disable Shared runner.
```

Comment: in my CI/CD, I don't see any Runner option. This is from the side navigation bar in my project. The options under my CI/CD are Pipelines, Editor, Jobs, Schedules

Answer (score 7):

They say that they will not `charge` anything on the account or store the details of the card, but they actually charge $1. (which is reversed instantly)

Hence you need a card with international transactions available. (if you're not in the US).

I wonder why this declaration is not made on the website. Definitely doesn't look good on part of such a large company as GitLab!

As for the answer, providing a credit/debit card with international transactions enabled and $1 to spare does the deed.

Answer (score 5):

Gitlab updates about free pipeline minutes available on GitLab.com.

Solve proplem:

1. Provide a credit or debit card and use the 400 free minutes with shared runners.
2. You use your own runner and disable shared runners for their project.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

This maybe is a bug, please see https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/331959

---

All answer above is good, but maybe have a little bit misunderstanding about credit card preauthorization.

When we use credit card, shop will request bank freeze some credits (usually the total price) for this transaction. At a moment (depended on shop), they ask bank for payment and get cash. After this, bank send bill to user.

Preauthorization is a action of freeze credits.

If shop doesn't ask bank for payment, bank will not give them cash and customer will not receive bill.

Preauthorization is a way that check validity of credit card. A common amount is one U.S. dollar. This is very common on Google Play and App Store when you add a new card.

Gitlab use this way to **confirm whether the credit card is valid** as same.

Although it depends on their internal operations, I think Gitlab does not need to cancel the transaction specifically, the only one thing need to do is that make sure they won’t ask bank pay for this preauthorization.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Shivem Khandelwal posted, I found this youtube video that goes through the process: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s3G0qxwT11c

The message that gitlab gives saying that it won't charge is a bit miss leading, because what happens is:

1. Gitlab charges you $1
2. Gitlab rollback the transaction

This flow sometimes is not logged into the credit card. Maybe this is the reason behind the sentence "we won't charge"

Answer (score 0):

**Disable** 'Enable instance runners for this project'

[image]

Answer (score -4):

it happens when you have multiple projects. try to solve by yourself. easy chhe ne

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).